# org.apache.tiles.util.TilesIOException

Tags: java, spring, jsp, struts2

Hello I am working on struts project. I have deployed the project on Linux tomcat server. After clicking on the page it is giving following error. But the same page is working very well in my local machine.

```
HTTP Status 500 - ServletException including path '/Pages/Layout/baseLayout.jsp'.

type Exception report

message ServletException including path '/Pages/Layout/baseLayout.jsp'.

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.tiles.TilesException: ServletException including path '/Pages/Layout/baseLayout.jsp'.
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:614)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult.doExecute(TilesResult.java:105)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:362)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:266)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:165)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:252)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:179)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:235)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:130)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:165)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:179)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.obs.util.IsValidUserInterceptor.intercept(IsValidUserInterceptor.java:15)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.obs.util.IsValidUserCustomerInterceptor.intercept(IsValidUserCustomerInterceptor.java:15)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:488)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
root cause

org.apache.tiles.util.TilesIOException: ServletException including path '/Pages/Layout/baseLayout.jsp'.
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.wrapServletException(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:298)
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:200)
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:179)
    org.apache.tiles.context.TilesRequestContextWrapper.dispatch(TilesRequestContextWrapper.java:72)
    org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesRequestContext.dispatch(StrutsTilesRequestContext.java:88)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:606)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult.doExecute(TilesResult.java:105)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:362)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:266)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:165)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:252)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:179)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:235)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:130)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:165)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:179)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.obs.util.IsValidUserInterceptor.intercept(IsValidUserInterceptor.java:15)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.obs.util.IsValidUserCustomerInterceptor.intercept(IsValidUserCustomerInterceptor.java:15)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:488)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: IO Error executing tag: JSPException including path '/Pages/Customer/foreignTransfer.jsp'.
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:912)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:845)
    org.apache.jsp.Pages.Layout.baseLayout_jsp._jspService(baseLayout_jsp.java:442)

    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:179)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:235)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:130)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:165)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:179)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.obs.util.IsValidUserInterceptor.intercept(IsValidUserInterceptor.java:15)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.obs.util.IsValidUserCustomerInterceptor.intercept(IsValidUserCustomerInterceptor.java:15)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:488)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
root cause

org.apache.tiles.util.TilesIOException: JSPException including path '/Pages/Customer/foreignTransfer.jsp'.
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.wrapServletException(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:300)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:82)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:73)
    org.apache.tiles.context.TilesRequestContextWrapper.dispatch(TilesRequestContextWrapper.java:72)
    org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesRequestContext.dispatch(StrutsTilesRequestContext.java:88)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:283)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:140)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:117)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport.execute(RenderTagSupport.java:1
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:165)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:179)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.obs.util.IsValidUserInterceptor.intercept(IsValidUserInterceptor.java:15)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.obs.util.IsValidUserCustomerInterceptor.intercept(IsValidUserCustomerInterceptor.java:15)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:488)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
root cause

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /Pages/Customer/foreignTransfer.jsp (line: 347, column: 92) Attribute qualified names must be unique within an element
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:443)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:89)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a problem with your JSP foreignTransfer.jsp. It has a duplicate attribute within same element as exception below explains.

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /Pages/Customer/foreignTransfer.jsp (line: 347, column: 92) Attribute qualified names must be unique within an element

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem in the jsp.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation point to vote up your answer:(

Comment: @shan upvote is fine..you can select the tick mark to accept my answer :-)